# How to deploy C# console app to RHEL host that has FIPS enabled

Tags: c#, sql-server, rhel8

I have a C# console application, named SqlTest, that simply connects to SQL Server and reads one column. I've reduced it down for simplicity. It works fine when I run it locally, but fails when I deploy it to a RHEL (8.9 Ootpa) host that has FIPS enabled. It doesn't totally fail because it does start to run the app, but fails when it trys to connect to SQL Server. I can see it output the statement "Query data example:" letting me know that it is running.

I'm not too familiar with deploying C# apps to Linux and I'm hoping that I'm just missing a step or two. Or if there is something I need to add because the Linux host is FIPS enabled for the app to be able to connect to SQL Server.

Below is the code for my app and the steps I took to deploy it to the RHEL host.

Steps to deploy app to RHEL host:
In Visual Studio Community 2022 (Version 17.7.4), open the terminal window
View -> Terminal

In the terminal, run the following command:
dotnet publish -c release -r rhel.8-x64 --self-contained

After the above command is ran, it creates a publish folder in the release folder. Copy this folder to the RHEL host

In the RHEL host, cd into the publish folder and run the SqlTest app using the following command:
./SqlTest

program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

namespace sqltest
{
    class Program
    {
        public partial class MySqlData
        {
            public decimal my_id { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                builder.UserID = "my_user";
                builder.Password = "Super_Secret_Pass123";
                builder.DataSource = "myhost.com\\myhost_dev";
                builder.InitialCatalog = "DEV";
                builder.TrustServerCertificate = true;
                builder.Encrypt = true;
                builder.MultiSubnetFailover = true;
                builder.IntegratedSecurity = false;
                String sqlQuery = "SELECT my_id FROM my_table";

                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\nQuery data example:");
                    Console.WriteLine("=========================================\n");

                    connection.Open();

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                MySqlData my_data = new MySqlData();
                                my_data.my_id = reader.GetDecimal(0);
                                Console.WriteLine("{0}", my_data.my_id);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the error I get after running it:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was
> successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred
> during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 -
> An internal exception was caught)  --->
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication
> failed, see inner exception.  ---> Interop+OpenSsl+SslException: SSL
> Handshake failed with OpenSSL error - SSL_ERROR_SSL.  --->
> Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:141A3066:SSL
> routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:bad dh value    --- End of inner
> exception stack trace ---    at
> Interop.OpenSsl.DoSslHandshake(SafeSslHandle context, ReadOnlySpan`1 input, Byte[]& sendBuf, Int32& sendCount)    at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.HandshakeInternal(SafeFreeCredentials credential, SafeDeleteSslContext& context, ReadOnlySpan`1 inputBuffer,
> Byte[]& outputBuffer, SslAuthenticationOptions
> sslAuthenticationOptions)    --- End of inner exception stack trace
> ---    at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter
> adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean
> isApm)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions
> sslClientAuthenticationOptions)    at
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost,
> X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols
> enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.EnableSsl(UInt32 options)
> at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
> exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, SqlCommand command, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.EnableSsl(UInt32 info, SqlConnectionEncryptOption encrypt, Boolean integratedSecurity, String serverCertificateFilename)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(SqlConnectionEncryptOption encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean& marsCapable, Boolean& fedAuthRequired, Boolean tlsFirst, String serverCert)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean withFailover)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)    at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool, Func`3 accessTokenCallback)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
> options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
> DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
> DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
> pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
> DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
> owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
> oldConnection)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
> owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
> oldConnection)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
> allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
> owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
> connection)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
> outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
> TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
> retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides
> overrides)    at sqltest.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> C:\Users\my_user\source\repos\SqlTest\SqlTest\Program.cs:line 35
> ClientConnectionId:568dade4-7a67-4126-bddf-95897f9f61a1 Error
> Number:-2146893019,State:0,Class:20

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question to include the error that I'm seeing

Comment: Error 141A3066... seems like your target server is trying to use DHE cipher suites, which is something that your FIPS policies on RHEL don't support.

Comment: Please show a Wireshark trace with the Client Hello and Server Hello. In particular we need to see the TLS version number and the list of cipher suites. There needs to be a common version and cipher for a connection to be made.

Comment: I agree it does appear to be an issue caused my mismatching/unsupported ciphers. Unfortunately I won't be able to resolve that since this was just to see if we could find an alternative method to connecting to SQL server with the available resources we have. Thanks again for all of the help!